# Code-First Referencing Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am currently struggling with some mapping properties on my models.  Here are my two models.
What I am looking to do is only have unique PersonTypes (ie MD, Nurse) in my table and the person model reference these personTypes.

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.PersonTypes = new List<PersonType>();
        this.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FacilityId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(200), Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(200)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(200), Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? SpecialtyId { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    // Mapped Properties

    [ForeignKey("FacilityId")]
    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SpecialtyId")]
    public virtual Specialty Specialty { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonType> PersonTypes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonType
{
    public PersonType()
    {
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(200), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Person1 = MD, Nurse - Person2 = MD - Person3 = Nurse, CNP

I don't want to have MD in my PersonType Table 2 times from above example.  Is this possible.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get duplicates"? Can you show the code that produces them?

Comment: So you do not want to be able to find which `Person`'s are `MD`'s? You just want to a property on a `Person` that specifies which `PeronsType` it is? That is a simple `PersonType` enumeration then. You do not need a `PersonType` table for that.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I gather that you have many-to-many relationship between Persons and PersonTypes. For EF CodeFirst to understand this you have to create symmetric navigation property in you PersonType: `public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons`.

Comment: It certainly is many-to-many, but there are more ways to express these in code-first. I would prefer a model where `PersonType` does not have a `Persons` collection.

Comment: I have tried that and I get duplicates in my PersonType Table.  I would like to keep PersonType clean with no duplicates, just a plain table with items.  I almost need a reference table with PersonId, PersonTypeId?

Comment: @GertArnold As far as I know there's only one other way to express many-to-many, and it requires configuration in code (`HasMany().WithMany()`). It's fine by me but it's somewhat harder to explain.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, Yes, that's what I would do. Joshua: yes, for many-to-many between unique entities you're going to need a junction table as you described.